# How to ignore sub-folder requests and continue processing URI mapping using mod_rewrite?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

An default example file for a default Wordpress deployment is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have a special case scenario though where I have a subfolder as such in my root web directory that I need ignored:

```
/folderA/folderB/specialCase.php
```

I basically need:

```
/folderA/folderB/*
```

to be ignored, but I **do** need:

```
/folderA/folderB/specialCase.php
```

to be directly accessible and served.

The problem is that */folderA/folderB* currently maps to a URI in my Wordpress install. Since the directories actually exist in the web root folder, currently Apache is serving up the index.php within */folderA/folderB/*.

I need it to skip over these subfolders and continue processing URI mappings as usual, **except** in the special case where *specialCase.php* is requested?

Difficult? Hard? I'm stumped at the moment. Have been experimenting with the [PT] *(passthrough)* flags but no luck so far.

Thanks!

Comment: How is **/folderA/folderB currently maps to a URI in my Wordpress install**?

Comment: */folderA/folderB/* is a permalink path in the Wordpress install. Problem though is because /folderA/folderB directories actually *EXIST* in webroot the web server is serving */folderA/folderB/index.php*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just check for that specific file, and serve it. Otherwise redirect the rest to the wordpress rules. Maybe something like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folderA/folderB/specialCase\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folderA/folderB/?$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Also you could probably add another .htaccess in folderA/folderB/.htaccess with this

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
```

Which will also prevent it from serving index.php in that directory only.